# making an Ad-hoc network (2 Windows PCs)

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, ad-hoc-network

I'm trying to connect 2 Windows 10 laptops using Wireless adapters
*) I wanna try having both PCs connect to Internet on their own,
*) and I want try to have one of the PCs give Internet to the other.

I've tried the "netsh" "way" (as in here:)
https://www.lifewire.com/what-is-an-ad-hoc-wireless-network-2377409

but it turns out new Windows 10 versions/builds don't have this anymore.

There is the new "Hotspot" way (access from Control Panel), but I think this only provides Internet, and doesn't make an Ad-hoc connection/network. How do I do that (have an Ad-hoc network in new Windows 10)?

Comment: Try to follow [this tutorial](https://www.dignited.com/34490/how-to-connect-two-windows-10-pcs-without-a-router/), which might work better. Remember to give the PCs static IP addresses.

Comment: the netsh way is deprecated in Windows 10.. these instructions don't work anymore.

Comment: (I mean the new build/version)

Comment: Strange. Are you sure that `netsh wlan show drivers` shows "Hosted network supported  : Yes"?

Comment: It says no. I'm gonna try another adapter, but how does it know which one I mean by that command?

Comment: also, if I make hotspot, from Windows Control Panel, using the PC as a router/hotspot actually works (connecting from my smartphone device

Comment: the other wireless adapter says No Hosted network supported... so that means both wireless devices not able to make ad-hoc network?

Comment: Please note/consider I solved the problem by updating drivers

Answer (score 2):

To summarize the above comments:

Before trying to create an ad-hoc wireless network (or hotspot), one should
test in an elevated Command Prompt that the command `netsh wlan show drivers`
shows "Hosted network supported  : Yes".

If it doesn't, then the WiFi driver does not have this capability.
The solutions in this case are:

1. Check if a later version exists for the driver of the wireless adapter,
   or if this does not help:
2. Replace the wireless adapter. If the adapter cannot be replaced,
   add an additional external adapter connected via USB
   (after checking its specifications).